# foreach loop working but category_name not looping inside of Wp_Query :(

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I want to query category from post. Category is showing in output but `category_name` is not looping in `wp_query` array. How can i solve this?

You can see my code below:

```
public function minzel_blog_cats() {
$settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
$blog_cats = $settings['blog_category'];
//if (!empty($blog_cats) && !is_wp_error($blog_cats)) {
    foreach ($blog_cats as $blog_cat) {
        //$cat_options[$blog_cat->slug] = $blog_cat->slug;
        //$cat_options[$term->slug] = " '".$term->slug.", '";
        $cat_options = $blog_cat." , ";
        echo $blog_cat.", ";
    }
//}

return $cat_options;
}

$default    = [
    'posts_per_page'    => $blog_post_per,
    'orderby' => $blog_grid_orderby,
    'category_name' => " ' ".$this->minzel_blog_cats()." ', ",
    'order' => $blog_grid_order,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `$cat_options` again and again inside loop, you need to assign all name using concatenation operator (`.`)

```
public function minzel_blog_cats() {
    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
    $blog_cats = $settings['blog_category'];
    $cat_options = '';//create an empty string
    foreach ($blog_cats as $blog_cat) {
        $cat_options .= $blog_cat." , "; //assign all names
    }
    return $cat_options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace default parameter with below code and check.

```
$default    = [
    'posts_per_page'    => $blog_post_per,
    'orderby' => $blog_grid_orderby,
    'category' => " ' ".$this->minzel_blog_cats()." ', ",
    'order' => $blog_grid_order,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
];
```